# Selected Index on a DataFormCombobox

Tags: silverlight-3.0, dataform

Does anyone know of a simple way to set a selected index or item a SilverLight 3 dataform combobox?  All of the online documentation suggests that it can only be done via databinding, which I'm not using in one particular instance.

Thanks
~Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been made moot by the final release of Silverlight 3.